# Is it possible to provide external executor service to Hystrix?

Tags: executorservice, hystrix

I'm using Hystrix within Weblogic Application Server. I’m trying to provide Hystrix an external executor service (javax.enterprise.concurrent.ManagedExecutorService to be exact). This executor service is provided and managed by WAS.

Is possible to provide external executor service to Hystrix? Or maybe  it’s against Hystrix policy and executor service MUST be provided and managed by Hystrix itself?